# CSS width 100% including overflow

Tags: css, overflow

For various reasons, I have a nested `ol` inside of a `div`, where the contents of the list exceeds the size of the container.

Because the container has a fixed width, the list element's background does not exceed the viewable area of the container, yet the contents scroll properly.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNv5u/1/) showing a simplified example of what I'm trying to explain.

I would like the width of the contained element to match that of the overflowed content.  In the jsFiddle, that would mean the red background doesn't get cut off midway.

Thanks.

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 33% auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
}

div > ol
{
   background: red;
   width: 100%;
}​
```

Comment: why cant you just set the div's background to red?

Comment: what is the point? Why do you want to do this? The "why" is important to figuring out a solution.  And when you say you want the div to have the same width, do you mean you want the div to expand to the size of the list?

Comment: The reason why is because I was using a list element for alternating rows with different backgrounds, so I couldn't just make the background of the div the same (variable `li` heights).  Also, as stated, the container (the `div` in my **simplified** example) has a fixed width.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use `display: inline-block`. You can read more in the W3C specs.

Replace `width:100%` with `display:inline-block` in those two element styles.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, and that I didn't try that in all my experiments.  Changing the display property does exactly what I want it to do.  Thanks.

Comment: Because, occasionally, my list element did not overflow the container, I had also ended up adding `min-width: 100%;` to the `ol`.

Comment: Really? This is awesome but I'm not sure to understand why display block wouldn't use the overflow?